# How can I write this as CMD [ ... ] syntax?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

It's good practice to start the service with

```
CMD ["/go/bin/myapp"]
```

instead of

```
CMD /go/bin/myapp
```

In the first way, SIGTERMs are caught by the applicaiton, while in the second way, they are caught by the underlying `/bin/sh` script, which does not forward them to the service. I learned this from https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-cannot-be-killed-with-ctrl-c/13108/2.

I am having troubles to rewrite the following `CMD` command to the `CMD [ ...]` syntax:

```
CMD /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

I tried several alternatives but keep getting syntax errors. How can I do this? Is this maybe an application of `tini` (https://github.com/krallin/tini)?

Comment: You can also create a script containing

`envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

and launch

`CMD ["/bin/sh", "myscript"]` or `CMD /bin/sh myscript`

Comment: That's a good idea, but I am wondering if it is also possible directly within `CMD [ ... ]`. Also, shouldn't that be `CMD ["myscript.sh"]` instead of `CMD ["/bin/sh", "myscript.sh"]`?

Comment: @JohnSomen I've found this [article](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/) really helpful because it helps you understand step by step how `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` can work together and what happens with different combinations of `exec form` and `shell form`. These are also mentioned in the `Dockerfile` [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) but they are not very clear (IMHO). Under the ENTRYPOINT examples section, you will find some guidelines on how to use `exec "$@"` so that the final executable receives the Unix signals.

Comment: @tgogos Thank you, very interesting article indeed. I am trying to apply it. I will report here.

Comment: @tgogos That article was very helpful, thank you. I learned a lot there. Just so be sure, I asked a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681357/will-the-application-run-as-pid-1-and-will-signals-be-received-if-we-bootstrap-i